# Attempting to make a grid of numbers in Python, however the output is one vertical line

Tags: python

I am running this code to try to make a block of numbers

```
grid = [[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
        [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
        [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
        [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
        [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]]


def print_grid():
    for line in grid:
        for square in line:
            if square == 0:
                print(".", end=" ")
            else:
                print(square, end=" ")
            print()


print_grid()
```

however the output is one long list of numbers running down virtically like this:

```
5 
3 
. 
. 
7 
. 
. 
. 
. 
6 
. 
. 
1
```

etc etc
Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: move the `print()` back out of the inner loop

Comment: `print()` is indented one level too deep. Just de-dent it once so that it's in `for line in grid`.

Comment: BTW, you can move that `if` inline: `print("." if square == 0 else square, end=' ')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final print statement (the empty one) is happening after each square, not after each line. Try unindenting it by one level.